# PHP - make a phone call using voice modem

Tags: php, voice, modem

Is it possible to make phone call using PHP and voice modem?

PHP will run on local server (XAMPP).

I have found some solutions for asp.net (using 3rd party api and software which is fine IMO), but PHP is required for this project.

Comment: What is your goal? Play a prerecorded message to a given number? Talk with the remote end through your webserver?

Comment: Im building CRM and i would like to have ability to make a call, optionally record, and get response when it ended.

Answer (score 0):

You said a 3rd Party is okay, so [this](http://sonetel.com/en/help/support-center/help-topics/api/call-back-api/) might be interesting for you.

Please note that you will need to signup for an account with Sonetel in order to use the api. While this is free, making phone calls cost few cents.

Here's an example code to use their api. The api is initiating two phone calls, one to you and one to the person you are calling. It will first ring the number provided first and if this call is picked up, it will ring the second number and then connects both together.

```
$url='https://call.sonetel.com';
$data = array('email' => 'abc@xyz.com','password' => 'XXXXXXXXX','call1' => 'XXXXXXXXXX','call2' => 'XXXXXXXXXXXXX');
$data_to_send = http_build_query($data);
$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST"); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$data_to_send);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded'));
$result = curl_exec($ch);
```

Comment: Thanks, but this is not what im looking for.